# JMX connection fails with "handshake failed...expected JDWP-Handshake"

Tags: java, jmx, remote-debugging, jvisualvm

I'm trying to connect VisualVM to a remote JMX. IntelliJ can connect without hassle, but VisualVM fails with the following in log output:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
Debugger failed to attach: recv failed during handshake: Resource temporarily unavailable
Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - received >< - expected >JDWP-Handshake<
```

Here are the JVM properties I'm passing at runtime:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=50g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx50g -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=100.100.100.100 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5006 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Using VisualVM 1.3.9. Not sure why it fails why IntelliJ succeeds. I've tried disabling SSL auth, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The socket listening on 5005 is not a JMX listener, it's the [java debug wire protocol](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/introclientissues005.html) listener. As such, VisualVM will not be able to connect to that port, and that's why you're seeing a handshake failure.

Comment: okay solves most of the problem, except I enabled JMX on startup and set that as the port...so what am I missing here?

Comment: Well... I am fairly sure the debug port is bound first, so the JMX listener is probably failing silently, but it's not hard to say without seeing your config. Or... Perhaps JMX and jdwp are binding to the same port on different interfaces ?

Comment: Just updated my command line config, changed the JMX port to 5006, still no dice, I can connect VisualVM to the jstatd instance though

Comment: This solved the problem, it was Gradle: https://gist.github.com/zedar/82f10d1064b00cbea79d